# How can i do cross domain query using ajax & jsonp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv

I send ajax to url , but i get error. 
Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://webrates.truefx.com/rates/connect.html?q=ozrates&c=EUR/USD&f=csv&s=n",
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
})
```

Maybe i doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you add the error message you receive?

Comment: use https instead of http

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: EUR is not defined. In network i see responce  - "EUR/USD,1455791963836,1.11,264,1.11,269,1.11185,1.11500,1.11259". This is what i need , but i cant get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access data using JSONP, the server you are requesting the data from must format its response as JSONP.

You are getting an error because the response is **not** JSONP (it is CSV, which you asked for explicitly when you put `t=csv` in the query string).

Either:

- Use a different method to get the data
- Change the server so it responds with JSONP formatted data

Comment: There are some options to get this data through javascript? Or i need use curl ?

Comment: @genalitash — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy